# Which is more advisable using - Restful Service(End point) or a servlet with app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

I know App Engine uses the Jetty servlet container to host applications ,right now  we  are using Endpoint  which uses the RESTful services by which  mobile app(android) and  web client can communicate with app engine and can perform  insert update and remove operation  on  datastore using JDO or JPA.

This same  operation can also be used if a java servlet on app engine app,it also uses JDO or  JPA to communicate with data store ,

```
SO with app engine which is more advisable Endpoint(RESTful services) or servlet?
```

Any clarity on this will be really helpful.

thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve.

When you use endpoints, you can get autogenerated client-code and you can possibly end up with less boilerplate code. The endpoint code will handle all marshalling/unmarshalling of the data you send to the server. But you will also have to use the auto-generated code for all clients using the endpoint.

Using servlets you will have to do a bit more boilerplate coding and do all the marshalling yourselves, but you will have full control of what happens and you do not need to use the autogenerated code.

Comment: thanks for your answer,As our application is more web based we will be using servlet more ,but we will also be using restful services for our android application in future in which endpoint will be helpful for us!!